# dygraphs in R markdown tabsets not loaded properly

Tags: r, r-markdown, dygraphs, htmlwidgets

I am making multiple dygraphs in a R markdown document. Each dygraph should be in it's own tabset. The code for one of my dygraphs is the following:

```
# Make a dygraph
dygraph(xts_data, main = "Totaal van nieuwe tickets") %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5, 
          highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
          hideOnMouseOut = TRUE) %>%
  dyLegend(width = 600) %>%
  dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Dark2")[c(1,3,4)],
        fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 0.4)
```

This code is properly put within a tabset which is created through the following code:

```
## Ticket data {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
```

Now what seems to have is that each time I open a new tab, it doesn't properly display the dygraph. Only when I resize the compiled html document, the graph becomes properly visible again. Has anyone had a similar experience and knows how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like this got fixed here https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/commit/6ed9f961c7cafd414ae4b7c994f6e3b652d4884b and in news for `0.7` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dygraphs/NEWS.  Have you tried the newest `dygraphs`?

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the new dygraph package and now it seems to work perfectly !